# how to play video in iphone, xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

i am creating a movie application in iphone . i want to play a video in my application. My Video  url is located locally. Please anybody help me in  how can i play a video in my application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where is it located locally? In the application bundle?
If so, the URL is like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videoname" ofType:@"mov" inDirectory:@""]];
```

You can play most videos with Apple's MediaPlayer-framework.

Add the framework (MediaPlayer) to your project and import it in the `.h`-file, and create an instance of the MediaPlayer like this:

```
// .h:
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

// .m:
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[[player view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]]; // Frame must match parent view
[self.view addSubview:[player view]];
[player play];
[player release];
```

[MPMoviePlayerController-documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html)

Comment: I tried with `player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukSvjqwJixw"]];`, but its not working.

Comment: This question is form 2010 and iOS 3/4. Try making a new question if you are unable to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

THis code works:

```
- (void)embedYouTube {

    // If the url is like:
    //NSString *youtube = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVdpzBT7Jrg";

    // Change to:
    NSString *videoURL = @"http://youtube.com/embed/EVdpzBT7Jrg";

    NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                 <html>\
                 <head>\
                 <style type=\"text/css\">\
                 iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
                 body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
                 </style>\
                 </head>\
                 <body>\
                 <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
                 </body>\
                 </html>", videoURL];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    videoView.opaque = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];

}
```